# Unable to use array inside mapreduce programme

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to `hadoop` and I am using `hadoop` with `mongodb`. using `mongodb connector`. I have to develop `mapreduce` programm .

Here is my `mapper`

```
public static class Map extends Mapper < Object, BSONObject, Text, IntWritable > {
    public void map(final Object key, final BSONObject value, final Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(value.get("-ID"));
    System.out.println(value.get("-name"));
    System.out.println(value.get("parameter"));
    //String[] arr = (String[]) value.get("parameter");
    context.write(new Text("hello"), new IntWritable(4));
    }
}
```

My concern is if I uncomment above line in mapper then my mapper stops after printing only three statements. It does not iterate further otherwise it is working fine. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the checklist for using BSON input to map reduce [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Using-BSON-with-MapReduce)